# How to compare images to find the least blurry image?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, compare

How to compare images to find the least blurry image?

I want to automaticallz generate an image/thumbnail from a video.

I use ffmpg for that.

However once in a while the image is totally blurred and I want to get rid of the blurry images.

My idea was to create multiple images per video and than compare the images to eachother.

Now the question:

Is there a way to compare the blurryness of images?

Comment: It totally depends on how you define “blurry”. Computers don’t understand such concepts. What if the thumbnail is an accurate representation of a blurry video? What if the image is sharp, but highly pixelated? Look at things like psnr, ssim, and vmaf. That should help you understand objective video quality measurements.

Comment: Video will be professionaly recorded quality video, at least HD up to 8K, LOG with LUT applied, low compression. By blurry i mean motion blur only. Not that an image out of a whip pan is selected, where nothing can be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when choosing thumbnail for video.
My solution was to take 10 screenshots, each second apart and choose one with highest size.

Making screenshots with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -loglevel panic -ss *secondsinmovie* -i movie.mp4 -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 screenshot.jpg
```

Then, to fine tune it. Take that second and iterate over frames and again, choose highest filesize